# Vue 3 Overview & Detail view same router-link should be active

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This nav structure is given:

```
<router-link to="/">Dashboard</router-link>
<router-link to="/travels">Travels</router-link>
...
```

Travels contains a list with all Travel Locations like so:

```
<div v-for="travel of travels" :key="travel.id">
  <router-link :to="{name: 'Travel.Detail', params:{id:id}}">{travel.label}</router-link>
</div>
```

Router is working too:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/travels',
    name: 'Travels.Overview',
    component: () => import('@/views/projects/TravelsOverview.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/travels/:id',
    name: 'Travels.Detail',
    component: () => import('@/views/projects/TravelsDetail.vue'),
  }
```

A requirement now is that when selecting a travel and showing the TravelsDetail view  that the menu item for *Travels* stays active. As far as i understand children / nested routes like so:

```
{
    path: '/travels',
    name: 'Travels.Overview',
    component: () => import('@/views/projects/TravelsOverview.vue'),
    children:[
     {
       path: ':id',
       name: 'Travels.Detail',
       component: () => import('@/views/projects/TravelsDetail.vue'),
     }
    ]
}
```

Are only working WITHIN the parent view inside another  tag and cannot be used to "replace" the parent  correct?

So how it is possible to have such a structure with overview & detail views (full views) where in overview and detail view the link item still has the "active" class?

Answer (score 0):

Okey i've found a solution here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/router-active-class-on-submenu-parent/7027

```
<router-link to="/travels" custom v-slot="{ href, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }">
          <li :class="{ 'uk-active active': isActive || isExactActive || subIsActive('/travels') }">
            <a :href="href" @click="navigate"><span>Travels</span></a>
          </li>
        </router-link>
```

And in the method:

```
subIsActive(input) {
      const paths = Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input]
      return paths.some(path => {
        return this.$route.path.indexOf(path) === 0 // current path starts with this path string
      })
    }
```

Now every route that starts with /travels adds the active classes to the router-link item.